# Define operator ** in C++

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

How can I define operator `**` such that it can perform exponentiation of 2 numbers . eg `2 ** 3`. It should give answer as 8.

Or Indirectly is there any way I can do this with operator overloading instead of `#define` macros ?

Comment: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overload-operator

Comment: Just use [pow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/)

Answer (score 19):

You can't. You can only overload existing operators, and not for built in types.

Comment: I wonder ('cause I don't know) if the C++14 `opaque typedef`s can mock the builtin types to achieve the goal the OP is willing to achieve.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster literal numbers will always have type `int`. You may be able to use user-defined literals and stuff, but simple things like `2**16` will never work.

Comment: @n.m. I know what you say about the literals (that could be more than only int ;) but I'm just wondering/fantasizing about the `opaque typedef`s and if them could be used for something like the OP wants: `supertypedef int potatoes;` and a free operator: `potatoes operator *(const potatoe a, const potatoe b) { return std::pow(a, b); }` but it looks silly event to me now that I'm writing it

Answer (score 11):

You can't. You can only overload existing operators in C++; you cannot add new ones, or change the arity or associativity of existing operators. Even the preprocessor is powerless here - its identifiers cannot be symbols.

Comment: Of course, you can define new ones using the `named operator idiom` https://github.com/klmr/named-operator

Comment: @sehe Mind:blown. I'm used to metaprogramming and stuff, but this use of operator overloading never even crossed my mind. I'm favouriting the questions just for your link.

Comment: @sehe That's a fine idiom, I myself (re)discovered it back in 2005 or so, but it's unable to define the power operator with correct precedence and associativity.

Comment: True. I was merely mentioning it in the interest of broad horizons. Quick let me +1 your answer. It seems I forgot

Comment: Actually in The C++ Programming language by Bjarne Stroustrup I came across this question - Define a class Index to hold the index for an exponentiation function mypow(double, index).Find a way to have 2 ** 1 call mypow(2,1)

Comment: @poorva: actually in the book it's not 1, it's I (a Latin capital letter). This makes all the difference.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to make a compromise w.r.t. `**` and feel like obfuscating your code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    foo(int i) : i_(i) {}
    int operator*(int exp)
    {
        return std::pow(i_,exp);
    }
private:
    int i_;
};

struct bar {
} power_of;

foo operator*(int i, bar)
{
    return foo{i};
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << 2 *power_of* 3;  // prints 8
}
```

Otherwise, just use `std::pow`.

Comment: It is possible to add `#define $$ *power_of*`, so it will be `2 $$ 3`. Plus, I would use operator with right-to-left associativity, like `*=`, so result of `4 $$ 3 $$ 2` will be `262144`. [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Nb1H3R)

Answer (score 5):

Like the other answers noted, this isn't possible for built-in types **BUT** you can get this to work for custom types like so (minimum code sample):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

struct dummy;

struct Int
{
    int i;
    Int() : i(0) {}
    Int(const int& i) : i(i) {}
    dummy operator*();
};

struct dummy
{
    Int* p;
    dummy(Int* const p) : p(p) {}

    int& operator*()
    {
        return p->i;
    }
};

dummy Int::operator*()
{
    return dummy(this);
}

int operator*(const Int& lhs, const dummy& rhs)
{
    return std::pow(lhs.i, rhs.p->i);
}


int main()
{
    Int a(2);
    Int b(2);
    std::cout<< a ** b << std::endl; 
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/fuQ6Zj)

Comment: @poorva: that actually looks cleaner than my version. Nice one !

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted: **that isn't possible.** You can overload another operator, like `^`, for exponentiation, instead however on a simple type wrapper class/object.

But, if you're adventurous, another way, is to create a micro DSL that supports on-the-fly calculation of such an operator. [(A famous example of that is LISP in C++)](http://howtowriteaprogram.blogspot.com/2010/11/lisp-interpreter-in-90-lines-of-c.html)

However, given the effort involved, it may or may not be your cup of tea. However, it's worth knowing that such a possibility exists.

UPDATE:

**Operator-Overloading works by overloading *already existing operators.*** Why? Because if you could define your own, you will also have to define the precedence of such operators which can easily give way to abusing operators by abstracting away their original purpose - which increases difficulty when reading code. (At least that's the argument that's been made).

The closest operator that has a semantic meaning close to `**` is the caret operator. A naive and illustrative implementation of such an operator is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Int {
public:
    Int() {}
    Int(int i) : value(i) {}

    friend double operator^(const int& i, const Int& integer);
    friend double operator^(const Int& integer, const int& i);
    friend double operator^(const Int& lhs, const Int& rhs);
private:
    int value;
};

double operator^ (const int& lhs, const Int& rhs) {
    return std::pow(lhs, rhs.value);
}

double operator^ (const Int& lhs, const int& rhs) {
    return std::pow(lhs.value, rhs);
}

double operator^ (const Int& lhs, const Int& rhs) {
    return std::pow(lhs.value, rhs.value);
}


int main() {
    Int i1 = 10;
    Int i2 = 3;
    double result = i1 ^ i2;

    std::cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there any way by which i can make 2 ** 3 call a function lets say mypow (int ,int); ?

Comment: Actually in The C++ Programming language by Bjarne Stroustrup I came across this question - Define a class Index to hold the index for an exponentiation function mypow(double, index).Find a way to have 2 ** 1 call mypow(2,1)

Comment: @poorva: correct. However, I believe you're missing the point of the exercise: it's to create class that can parse and perform calculations like: `2 ** 1`. You *could* use operator overloading, but there's as C++ doesn't support operator overloading to create an operator like: `**` natively (note, I said natively), then the exercise is obviously relegated to utilizing a different understanding and application of C++ to solve that issue. The hint is that's it's either a parsing problem that can be done with Macros at compile time, or with Classes, Objects and Functions at runtime.

Comment: [operater_overloading](http://pastebin.com/6fd5FTp4) This works but is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: @poorva: There are many ways to do it, whether it's right or not, depends on the situation / context. What may be right for you or me, may not not necessarily be right for someone else. If it works, and you understand it: its benefits as well as its shortcomings, then that's all that matters.

Comment: @jrd1: It most certainly is _not_ "all that matters". Why do you spare no thought for your colleagues, present and future?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "I cannot create what I do not know." If the OP doesn't know what he uses, he can't create. Hence, he has to understand it. That's what I do, that's what everyone does (at some point or another). **I am not disregarding anyone.** No, not at all. If anything, you have to be able to understand something before you can express that idea, ideology and associated gestation to someone else. My post was indicative of that. :)

Comment: @jrd1: Yes, understanding it yourself is of course a step along the way. I'm only saying that, contrary to your statement, that is not "all that matters": you _must_ make sure that your colleagues understand it too, either by explaining it at the time, or deferring this by documenting it in writing (or both). Of course sometimes those steps collapse into the empty work set if the code is trivial enough that they _already_ understand, but it's your responsibility to be sure of this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're correct. I'll keep that in mind in future. Thanks for the feedback, though! [That's you ensuring that I comprehend your comment] ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload operators for built-in types. I'd use `operator ^` for such purpose for custom types.

Comment: I would not. For one, it has the wrong precedence. For two, no. Just no.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the set of operators that can be overloaded in C++ is fixed and does not include the ** operator.  You might think of using `operator^()` instead, but it turns out that ^ has the wrong precedence to serve as an exponentiation operator.

In short, there's not much you can do about this, unfortunately.